# How to center a ul (nav) that has flexible width

Tags: css

I am trying to create the nav of

[http://forrst-production.s3.amazonaws.com/posts/snaps/59125/mega.jpg?1297328693](http://forrst.com/posts/New_Personal_Portfolio_Blog_Header-4za)

the nav width will expand or contract according to the width of inner list items. How can I acheive that? or must I set a fixed width for the nav?

Comment: There's a lot of different things you could do here. Will there always be 5 items? Is that ribbon thing fixed width, or does it resize according to the viewport width? My first thought is setting `width: 20%`, `float: left`, and `text-align: center` on each menu item.

Comment: So basically you want to achieve that, centered, without setting the width of the ribbon?

Comment: Can you clarify what you expect to be achieved from the bounty that the accepted answer does not cover? Thanks.

Comment: Oh actually I was intending to award the current answer with a bounty as I felt, ...  err I have too many points for a noob (dont really deserve it)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Make each item and the ribbon ends `display:inline-block`, then use `text-align:center` on the parent.

Comment: Then I will get something like -> http://imgur.com/sz0zc.jpg where the ul gets the width of the containing element? http://jiewmeng.kodingen.com/demos/wp-wip/comp.html